# woocommerce REST api on the website's front-end

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, api

I want to use AJAX for product listing (with "show more" functionality), AJAX based search etc. on the front-end of a Wordpress/Woocommerce website. It seems like a simplest approach here would be to use Woocommerce REST API.

- What is the recommended approach here, when i only need to use the /products endpoint? Is it possible to disable for instance the /orders endpoint?
- Since I have to use Consumer Key and Consumer Secret keys, what is the recommended way to use them within the Javascript functions, when I use Wordpress on the backend?

I would be glad, if someone can point me to the right direction, maybe the REST API is a wrong approach here altogether?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably change it so that the /products endpoint didn't need authentication, or accepted a normal WP REST API nonce as authentication, rather than trying to set up oauth or client secrets for JavaScript to use. And you can leave the /orders endpoint with the original authentication.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply! how would that be implemented? secrets are required for the woocommerce rest, right? i could use a normal wordpress rest (/wp-json/wp/v2/product), but i won't have access to the woocommerce fields there (like price and images) i reckon.

Comment: I'd guess there are hooks you can use to override the authentication but I don't know WooCommerce well enough sorry. However here's a plugin that looks like it does this for you in a round-about way, by proxying the public interface rather than changing the authentication though: [Public Woo Api](https://wordpress.org/plugins/public-woo-api/). I think I'd rather change the authentication on the existing endpoints though if possible.

Comment: Here's the [REST authentication code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.2/includes/class-wc-rest-authentication.php). It doesn't look hookable, no, but if you register a higher-priority (= lower number) determine_current_user filter that checks if you're using an allow-public WooCommerce API and returns a dummy user then you'll skip WooCommerce's own checks. I'd still verify a nonce there though.

Comment: this is absolutely perfect - with the plugin it works as intended and i don't have to deal with hiding the secrets or blocking the endpoints, thanks!

Comment: best plugin for front end REST API with woo-commerce

https://mlmtrees.com/product/woocommerce-b2c-rest-api